# Updating a column of each row in a table and saving changes in the database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

For the video player I'm building I have a database of .mp4 video files created in Visual Studio's server explorer. The database has a single "Videos" table consisting of the following columns:

- ArtistName,
- SongTitle,
- hddPath,
- songDuration.

I have filled all except the songDuration column manually. I'm using a component for my video player which has a method that returns a song's duration after it has been loaded in a player I have set. Don't bother with the player, just bear in mind that the call `component.getduration(hddPath)`, where `hddPath` is a string, returns a `string` in the following format: `hh:mm:ss`.

I can loop through the table rows and get the duration of each song in a for each statement:

```
DataTable dt = myDataSet.Tables["Videos"];
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   component.loadsound(0, row["hddPath"].ToString());  // 0 represents the index 
                                                       // of the player
   string duration = component.getduration(0);  // gets the duration of the song
                                                // loaded in player 0
}
```

But how do I update each row's "hddPath" column with the duration string and save it in my database?

Comment: What is your exact problem? I assume you know how to query your database? Are you asking how to write the SQL query to update data? Or is it some C# code that you are missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you

- have a DataAdapter associated with the DataSet
- and have update commands associated with it (e.g., via a CommandBuilder instance)
- and have a column in the DataTable for the duration (and assign the new value to it)

then you can send the updates to the database via the DataAdapter:

```
myDataAdapter.Update(myDataSet);
```

If you didn't use a DataAdapter to fill up the data set (which is what it sounds like from the OP), then it would also be possible to execute commands directly via an `SqlCommand` object. It might look something like the following statements.  Note that you would want to simply update the parameter value in the loop and run the `ExecuteNonQuery` method each iteration (as opposed to creating a new command object each time).  I'm unsure what the primary key (`pk` in the example) would be for your specific case.  If the only fields are the ones shown in the OP, then I suspect it would the hddpath, since that sounds as if it would be unique.

```
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand();
myCmd.CommandText = "update thetable set duration = @duration where pk=@pk";
myCmd.CreateParameter();
SqlParameter duration = new SqlParameter("@duration", 1234);
myCmd.Parameters.Add(duration);
SqlParameter pk = new SqlParameter("@pk", 1);
myCmd.Parameters.Add(pk);
myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

There are a number of overloads for the SqlParameter objects.  Pick the appropriate one.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your question should actually read: "how do I update each row's songDuration column".

If that is the case, then have you tried:

```
row["songDuration"] = component.getduration(0);
```

and then outside of the loop:

```
yourDataAdapter.Update(dt);
```

There is more information on how to update records in the database [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233819%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

Create your update method something like this:

```
  private void UpdateDurationofMyHddPath(string hdpath,string duration) //Add other parameters that you need
 {
  // Your  ado.net update sql stuff  
  //Update yourColum Set duration=@duration  where hddpath=@hdpath

 }
```

Add Method on your loop:

```
DataTable dt = myDataSet.Tables["Videos"];
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   component.loadsound(0, row["hddPath"].ToString());  // 0 represents the index 
                                                       // of the player
   string duration = component.getduration(0);  // gets the duration of the song
                                                // loaded in player 0
   string hdpath = row["hddPath"].ToString();

   //Update  hdpath duration

   UpdateDurationofMyHddPath(hdpath,duration);

}
```

Regards